# Pass parameters to Celery on_error task

Tags: python, celery

I'm using `celery` with `rabbitMQ` as a broker to manage asynchronous tasks.

I'm chording some tasks together and when each of them has finished, I'm running a *concatenation task* that will join each result. These collection of tasks is identified by a **report_id** set by me.

```
chord([task1.s(report_id=report_id), task2.s(report_id=report_id)...]) \
 (concat_task.s(report_id=report_id).set(queue='default') \
 .on_error(on_chord_error.s().set(queue='default')))
```

And this is my custom `on_error` task:

```
@celery_app.task
def on_chord_error(request, exc, traceback):
    logger.error('Chord {0!r} raised error: {1!r}'.format(request.id, exc), exc_info=(type(exc), exc.args, traceback))
    # BaseHandler.remove_placeholder(???report_id???)  # cleaning action
```

My problem is on the `on_error`: Every time the chord fails (for any reason) I need to have the **report_id** (not to be confused with the request.id) passed to it in order to perform a cleaning action. However the [documentation](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html) I found is vague on this. It seems I cannot pass the request_id as parameter of the task signature as I am doing for the singles and concatenation tasks.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `on_chord_error.s(report_id=report_id)`, can this work?

Comment: Unfortunately not, already tried

Comment: Related question [How do you ensure a Celery chord callback gets called with failed subtasks?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52324482) demonstrates how to pass extra info to the error callback.