# What is the signature of the celery `on_error` handler and how do I pass arguments to it?

Tags: python, celery

I saw this question which was unanswered: [Pass parameters to Celery on_error task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59575336/pass-parameters-to-celery-on-error-task)

My first question is, what is the signature of the error handler we can pass to a Celery task using `on_error(...)` or `apply(..., link_error=...)`.

In the link above (pass [Pass parameters to Celery on_error task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59575336/pass-parameters-to-celery-on-error-task), their `on_error` has signature:

```
multiple.on_failure(exc, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo)
```

In this link from the docs about [Canvas](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html) , the signature is:

```py
@app.task
def log_error(request, exc, traceback):
    with open(os.path.join('/var/errors', request.id), 'a') as fh:
        print('--\n\n{0} {1} {2}'.format(task_id, exc, traceback), file=fh)
```

In this other link from the docs: [Calling Tasks](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/calling.html), the signature is:

```py
@app.task
def error_handler(uuid):
    result = AsyncResult(uuid)
    exc = result.get(propagate=False)
    print('Task {0} raised exception: {1!r}\n{2!r}'.format(uuid, exc, result.traceback))
```

In my own codebase, I see people using:

```py
def handle_error(*args, **kwargs):
```

In addition, can you set a breakpoint using `rdb` inside of an `on_error` handler? Also why does the handler have to be a `@task`?